# NSURL returns nil

Tags: swift

Here is an example of my URL:

```
let urlString = "https://example.com/img/list/mobile/7156-292.jpg"
```

when I pass it to `NSURL(string: urlString )` it returns `nil`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: cannot reproduce, works in my playground.

Comment: 1. Post real code that actually reproduces the problem. 2. Why are you using `NSURL` in Swift? Use `URL`.

Comment: Does the URL work if you copy it into a browser?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery That's mostly irrelevant. There are many URLs that will work in a browser but will result in `nil` when passed to `NSURL(string:)`.

Comment: @rmaddy why is that?

Comment: @Honey because a browser does all kinds of things such as add `http://` if needed or properly encodes special characters (such as spaces). `NSURL` does none of those things for you.

Comment: @rmaddy I posted the real snippet code. Also I tried your suggestion by using `URL` instead of `NSURL` but getting the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updated output explains your issue. There is a newline character at the end of `urlString`. You need to cleanup the string from wherever you are obtaining those URLs.

```
let cleanURL = badURL.trimmingCharacters(in: . whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Comment: @Mark.Ben I would argue that the backend should provide clean data because it can be used my any number of clients (front-ends). Why should every client need to clean the data when the server should do it correctly? Having said that, I have no idea where the newline is coming from. It could be a problem with the backend or it could be a problem with whatever your code is doing.

Comment: I totally agree. I'm getting the entire urlString from the server without manipulating it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your edit, it appears that all of your URL strings end in a newline. A newline is not a valid character to have in a URL.

In other words, your URL actually looks like

```
let urlString = "https://new.domain.com/img/list/mobile/7156-292.jpg\n"
```